# could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges

Tags: shell, command

Hello Iam trying to create a `.command` to double click a set some modification in Security&Privacy OS X.
Here is what I tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  sudo spctl --master-disable
  chmod u+x ~/Desktop/disable.command
```

But it says that there is no permission. I tried with a simple hello word example and it says the same. What can I possible do to run this command file.
thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy fix. In terminal, CD to the directory of the file, then type in chmod u+x filename.command

Hopefully this works for you like it did for me!